# Upgrading to Helios: can I open my Galileo workspace in Helios?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I'm upgrading to Helios now and I'm wondering if it's ok if I keep using my Galileo workspace in Helios, or if I need to create a brand new workspace under Helios.

Wondering if my old workspace will work or if workspaces are not forward compatible.

Comment: I read that on another site that if you do you're not guaranteed that your old workspace will work in the previous version of eclipse if you open in it in a later version.  I'm not so concerned about that, but I after reading that I wanted to see what others thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are compatible. The only thing you have to take into consideration is, that workspace and project ettings may include special builders (e.g. for eclipse GMF, for GWT and whatever).

So first of all you will have to reinstall those plug-in for you workspace projects to work fine, and secondly new plug-in versions may force you to tune the project settings a bit tweaking builder versions. However, this should not be a big deal at all and in principle upgrading to helios shouldn't harm your workspace

Answer (score 0):

delete .eclipse folder in your application data folder on windows or /home/you/ on linux